# Can't save files from Live session

Tags: boot, root

As a result of a problem I can not solve , I decided to reinstall Ubuntu , but before do this I want to save all the files I have on my hard drive from CD passing through " Ubuntu Live "
The problem is that I had secured access to Ubuntu password and now from "ubuntu live" I'm not allow to save all files: on some folder ( moreover the most important ) I found a gray X and if I try to open them I get an error message : "`This location could not be displayed . You do not hace the Necessary permission to view the contents of .......` "

After that, I tried with `sudo nautilus`

but unfortunately there was nothing to do, when I write it, the terminal return this

[image: picture4]

If I try to give again the command `sudo nautilus`, the response change

[image: picture5]

I tried to follow various guides from this forum where it's said to try to terminal with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus  
sudo apt-get install nautilus  
sudo apt-get install samba
```

but the result will not change

Comment: Right click on one of these directories, select *Properties* and go to the *Permissions* tab. Who is the owner of these files and what are the permissions?

Comment: The owner is "user#1000" and the group is "1000", but it's tha same also for the file I can reach, open or copy on tha external HD, like the .mp3
Well, the main directory have "root" like owner
home --> root     INSTEAD    images  -->  user#1000

Comment: Now I try to opena file while the terminal is open: ...it says   "FILENAME" image was truncated or incomplete